# How to get String from PFObject and display it into tableView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, pfobject

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"addCategoryCell")

    var user = self.searchResult[indexPath.row] as? [PFObject]
     println(user)
    cell.textLabel?.text = user["Article_Number"] as? String // error here
    return cell
}
```

I want to print the article number on the table row. I have tried this code but it's not working. In addition, the term `searchResult` contains objects array of array.

Comment: show `println(user)` also.

Comment: "could not find overload for "subscript " that accept the supplied argument"

Comment: Optional(<Inventory: 0x7f8569e47cf0, objectId: ZUjbuUnlI4, localId: (null)> {
    "Applicable_Tax_With_C_Form" = jfdighrgh843j;
    "Applicable_Tax_Within_State" = asfjerhgeruh3fvire;
    "Article_Number" = 123abc;
    Brand = afjeroijgi;
    Category = djfer;
    Detail = "\nerjgireigvve erg  gerge  regwrgwerg thg4gfgtr 45 45 grthw h4th45g 4 rg hwh whth wthh w";
    "Item_Name" = sjfefo;
    "Location_Code" = ajerghuefj;
    Unit = sdfjerhgueh;
    User = "<PFUser: 0x7f8569e6f990, objectId: GUXTIvxVJ2, localId: (null)>";
})

and this is the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your code this way:

```
var user = self.searchResult[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
println(user)
cell.textLabel?.text = user.objectForKey("Article_Number") as! String
return cell
```

Comment: This is the correct way to retrieve a string from a PFObject